# RUC Paraguayan validator

Tags: regex, regex-greedy

I want to make a validation for RUC from Paraguay.

Now I can validate this expression `^[0-9+#-]*$` and got this result `1234567-8`, but I also have to validate this values:
`1234567`           -> only numbers
`1234567A-8`        -> number follows by a only one letter follow by `-8`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
^[0-9]+[A-Z]?(-[0-9])?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/SHvG2B/1).

*Details*:

- `^` - string start
- `[0-9]+` - one or more digits
- `[A-Z]?` - an optional uppercase ASCII letter
- `(-[0-9])?` - an optional sequence of a `-` and a digit
- `$` - end of string.

Answer (score 0):

Two alternatives: the *very long* and *very short* versions. Both assumes that
RUC (without check digit) has a length of 6 to 8 characters.

1. The *very long* version:
   Here, the only alphanumeric character that could appear at the end of the document is the capital *A*.

```
^(?:(?!0)\d{6,8}|(?!0)\d{5,7}A)(?:-\d)?$
```

```
^           # Start of string
  (?:         # Start of first non-capturing group:
    (?!0)       # Negative lookahead (?!): avoid starting with zero
    \d{6,8}     # Digits (an equivalent is [0-9]); 6 to 8 times
      |           # Or
    (?!0)       # Negative lookahead (?!): avoid starting with zero
    \d{5,7}A    # Digits (an equivalent is [0-9]); 5 to 7 times, followed by an 'A'
  )           # End of first non-capturing group
  (?:         # Start of second non-capturing group:
    -\d         # A hyphen followed by a single digit
  )?          # End of second non-capturing group; '?' = 'optional': may or may not appear
$           # End of string
```

Version with capturing groups:

```
^((?!0)\d{6,8}|(?!0)\d{5,7}A)(-\d)?$
```

---

2. The *very short* version:
   In this case, only capital *A* or *B* or *C* or *D* can be the alphanumeric characters that could appear at the end of the document.

```
^[1-9]\d{4,6}[\dA-D](?:-\d)?$

# or

^[1-9]\d{4,6}[\dA-D](-\d)?$
```

```
^           # Start of string
  [1-9]       # Digits from 1 to 9 (avoid starting with zero)
  \d{4,6}     # Digits (an equivalent is [0-9]); 4 to 6 times
  [\dA-D]     # Digits or capital A/B/C/D
  (?:         # Start of non-capturing group:
    -\d         # A hyphen followed by a single digit
  )?          # End of second non-capturing group; '?' = 'optional': may or may not appear
$           # End of string
```

<sub>**Both tested in Javascript.**</sub>

---

- [What is a non-capturing group in regular expressions?](/q/3512471)
- [What does `?!` mean?](/q/12210807)

---

> *Fact: The letter "A" was added to the document numbers that were mistakenly duplicated.*